# Android-TV RecyclerView always keeps focus at top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv

Need help in implementing a RecyclerView for Android-TV where the **focus** is always on the **first item** of the list like here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uw8Iv_oMSiU&t=13s)

What I've done so far is to use **requestChildRectangleOnScreen** and calculate the scroll to the next child. But my highlight view also scrolls with it. How do I keep the focus intact and only scroll the RecyclerView instead of the other way around?

```
public class RecyclerViewFirstFocus extends RecyclerView {

int dx = 0, dy = 0;

public RecyclerViewFirstFocus(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RecyclerViewFirstFocus(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RecyclerViewFirstFocus(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}


@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    View nextFocusView = null;
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                    nextFocusView = FocusFinder.getInstance().findNextFocus(this, findFocus(), FOCUS_UP);
                    if (nextFocusView == null) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                    nextFocusView = FocusFinder.getInstance().findNextFocus(this, findFocus(), FOCUS_DOWN);
                    if (nextFocusView == null) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean requestChildRectangleOnScreen(View child, Rect rect, boolean immediate) {

    View focusView = child.findFocus();

    if (focusView == null)
        return false;

    focusView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            focusView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            focusView.getHeight();

            Rect rectFocus = new Rect();
            focusView.getDrawingRect(rectFocus);
            offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(focusView, rectFocus);
            if (getLayoutManager().canScrollHorizontally()) {
                dx = rectFocus.left;
            } else if (getLayoutManager().canScrollVertically()) {
                dy = rectFocus.top - 350;
            }

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (immediate) {
                        scrollBy(dx, dy);
                    } else {
                        smoothScrollBy(dx, dy);
                    }
                }
            }, 150);
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

}

Has anyone implemented this before? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you using leanback library for your TV app?

Comment: No, I'm not using the lean-back library given it's limitations. Mine is a hybrid list with multiple view types and has nested recyclerview's